# uninitialized constant Rails::Server (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, server

Currently while trying to set up my ruby files, i am running into this problem. Im not sure what the problem is, as Rails is correctly installed. I am mostly new to Rails/Ruby, and am picking up rails. I haven't seen this problem else where.

I am working on windows 10, all gems are installed, and rails is installed.
Im am running this in RubyMine.

Here is the line where the error is thrown:

config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:' + Rails::Server.new.options[:Port].to_s

Here is an image of the console
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32nW0.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your need

```
require 'rails/commands/server
```

before call `Rails::Server`